# Getting Error While Inserting Spark dataframe into Hive table

Tags: pyspark, hive

While inserting a PySpark dataframe into Hive table, we are getting the following error occasionally. But can't identify the reason.

Error details is as follows:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o383978.insertInto.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.SaveAsHiveFile$class.saveAsHiveFile(SaveAsHiveFile.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.saveAsHiveFile(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.processInsert(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.run(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:340)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 34 (insertInto at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:565)    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:487)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:65)  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:645)    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:413)  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1334)    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:419)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException   at org.spark_project.guava.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:241)   at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:263)    at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doSparkAuth(AuthClientBootstrap.java:113)    at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(AuthClientBootstrap.java:80)     at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:262)     at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:192)     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient.lambda$fetchBlocks$0(ExternalShuffleClient.java:100)  at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:141)     at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:121)   at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient.fetchBlocks(ExternalShuffleClient.java:109)   at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.sendRequest(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:262)  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.org$apache$spark$storage$ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$send$1(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:539)     at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchUpToMaxBytes(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:534)    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:491)     ... 22 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784)     at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)  at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:259)    ... 34 more 
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1928)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1915)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1915)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1520)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2098)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:171)
    ... 34 more
```

Need to know the reason behind this error.